# Installing Tensorflow 2.0, I have GPU but not CUDA-Enabled, Does that means I can only used my CPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I read the TensorFlow documentation about how to install Tensorflow 2.0 with GPU on Windows (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

In the hardware requirement section, it states that it needs NVIDIA GPU with CUDA Compute Capability. When I saw CUDA-enabled GPU cards list (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), I just realized that my GPU was not on the list (I have NVIDIA GTX 1660 ti on my machine).

What I wanted to ask are:

1. Does it mean that I can't use my GPU for my Deep Learning Tensorflow implementation?
2. Does it mean that I have to install the CPU version of Tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: Your GPU has full CUDA support

Comment: but why I can't find GTX1660ti in here https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus ? TensorFlow documentation suggests that I should check my GPU on that list first.

Comment: Because someone at Nvidia didn't update the list

Comment: I hope so, thx for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tensorflow GPU on your laptop as your GPU supports CUDA. Install CUDA, then cuDNN and then, Tensorflow GPU.

You don't have to work with CPU version as you have a better option.

Comment: really? even though GTX 1660ti is not listed in here? https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Comment: search for GTX 1660 Ti compute capability. It has compute capability 7.5. So, CUDA should work.

Comment: I have tried it, and yes it does work. Someone from Nvidia should update the list.